# web.config Index Redirect

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I use a standard web.config file for my projects that are hosted on Windows servers.  It takes care of 2 tasks.

1. It redirects the non-www version of the site to the www version.
2. It redirects the index file to the root.

**See below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="index\.asp(?:l)?" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="example\.com$" />
                        </conditions>
                        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This works great, except for 1 problem.  The index redirect is redirecting all sub-directories to the main, index.

**For example:**

http://www.example.com/index.asp  is redirecting to http://www.example.com like it should.

But, http://www.example.com/about/index.asp  is also redirecting to http://www.example.com.  I would like it to redirect to http://www.example.com/about/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, after getting no response here, I posted on various .Net forums and finally got an answer.  This rule will fix it:

```
<rule name="redirect index.asp" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(\w*/)?index\.asp" />
       <conditions>
         <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain\.com$" />
       </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```